# Awk json log file which are greater that a time

Tags: json, linux, search, awk, command

I have a log file that each line is a long json dictionary. None of logs have the same length, but all of them have a **'_time_'** key which is an epoch time in **milliseconds**. I want to search inside this log file to extract logs which are greater than a time like 1450616426 (**second**). Some log examples are:

```
{'id':Bob, 'last-login':'...', '_time_':1444211444123456, ...}
{'name':'ehsan', 'family':'toghian', 'last-login':'2015-4-12', '_time_': 1444215425123465, .....}
```

How can I write an awk command? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: When providing sample input that you want to search based on some criteria, it's a good idea to include some lines that do and some that don't match your criteria, otherwise a script that just does `{print}` will produce the expected output. It's an EXTREMELY common issue on this site that someone posts a question and accepts the first answer that produces the expected output from that input, even when told it will fail for other input or is in other ways a terrible solution. Talking of output, yours is missing - always provide the expected output to go with your provided input.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    milli = $0
    sub(/.*_time_[^[:digit:]]+/,"",milli)
    sub(/[^[:digit:]].*/,"",milli)
    secs = milli / 1000
}
secs > tgt

$ awk -v tgt=1450616426 -f tst.awk file
{'id':Bob, 'last-login':'...', '_time_':1444211444123456, ...}
{'name':'ehsan', 'family':'toghian', 'last-login':'2015-4-12', '_time_': 1444215425123465, .....}
```

or with GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk -v tgt=1450616426 '(gensub(/.*_time_[^[:digit:]]+([[:digit:]]+).*/,"\\1",1) / 1000) > tgt' file
{'id':Bob, 'last-login':'...', '_time_':1444211444123456, ...}
{'name':'ehsan', 'family':'toghian', 'last-login':'2015-4-12', '_time_': 1444215425123465, .....}
```

Answer (score 0):

gawk

```
 awk -vl=1450616426 '{match($0,"_time_.: *([0-9]{10})[0-9]+",a);if(a[1]>l)print}' file
```

Comment: Saying "it didn't work" is like taking your car to a mechanic and only telling them "it doesn't work". Without some scenario and symptoms (what command line you executed, on what input, what happened wrt error messages, output, etc.) there is absolutely nothing we can do to help you debug the problem. As long as you're good being stuck with a script that "didn't worked" then that's fine, but if you want help you need to give us some kind of clue what you need help with.

Comment: @A-Ray - never use a variable named `l` in any code in any language as it looks far too much like the number `1`, completely indistinguishable in some fonts. I once spent hours trying to help someone debug a syntax error that we just could not figure out until I had her re-type the code in front of me and noticed she typed an `l` (el) instead of a `1` (one) and when I asked why she told me it was because she'd taken a typing course and that instructor had taught her it's faster to type an `l` than a `1` so she should always do that since they look the same anyway.